# Need to show an image from a mysql database

Tags: .net

I want to show an image saved in a **database** in a **picturebox**

'I tried with this:

```
Function Bytes_Imagen(ByVal Imagen As Byte()) As Image


    'Crear Variables
    Dim conexiones As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim Lector As MySqlDataReader
    Dim cSQL As String
    Dim cadconex As String

    'Abrir conexion con la BD
    cadconex = "Server=...;Database=bd; Uid=id;Pwd=constraseña"
    conexiones.ConnectionString = cadconex
    conexiones.Open()

    'Ingreso de Sentencia
    cmd = conexiones.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cSQL = "Select imagen from imagenes where id_imagen = 1 "
    cmd.CommandText = cSQL
    Lector = cmd.ExecuteReader

    Dim Bin As New IO.MemoryStream(Imagen)
    Dim Resultado As Image = Image.FromStream(Bin)

    frmInmuebles.picCasa1.Image = Bytes_Imagen(Lector.GetValue(0))



    'Cerrar Conexiones
    Lector.Close()
    conexiones.Close()


End Function
```

In this line appears an error:

> Val2.Bytes_Imagen(frmInmuebles.picCasa1.Image)

My function:

```
Function Bytes_Imagen(ByVal Imagen As Byte()) As Image


        'Crear Variables
    Dim conexiones As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim Lector As MySqlDataReader
    Dim cSQL As String
    Dim cadconex As String

    'Abrir conexion con la BD
    cadconex = "Server=...;Database=bd; Uid=id;Pwd=constraseña"
    conexiones.ConnectionString = cadconex
    conexiones.Open()

    'Ingreso de Sentencia
    cmd = conexiones.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cSQL = "Select imagen from imagenes where id_imagen = 1 "
    cmd.CommandText = cSQL
    Lector = cmd.ExecuteReader

    Dim Bin As New IO.MemoryStream(Imagen)
    Dim Resultado As Image = Image.FromStream(Bin)

    frmInmuebles.picCasa1.Image = Bytes_Imagen(Lector.GetValue(0))



    'Cerrar Conexiones
    Lector.Close()
    conexiones.Close()


End Function
```

This throws me the following error:

> Val2.Bytes_Imagen(frmInmuebles.picCasa1.Image)

Thank you very much for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware your function is recursive? In this line you call the function that contains the line itself:

```
frmInmuebles.picCasa1.Image = Bytes_Imagen(Lector.GetValue(0))
```

That may be the cause of your problem; there is nothing keeping your function from calling itself over an over again until the stack overflows.

Unfortunately, without knowing what 'the error' exactly is, we cannot answer your question properly.